# Is there a way to get the number of rows written to Azure table storage per minute?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

Is there a way to get the number of rows written to Azure table storage per minute. I wanted to get the metrics of MB of records written per minute, I can get this by finding the size of one row and multiplying it with the number of rows, but how do i get the number of rows written per minute?

Comment: What do you intend on doing with this data? I am pretty sure this sort of stuff is accessible via the [Azure Metrics](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh343264.aspx)

Comment: I am supposed to plot a chart saying how much our system is logging in traces over time.

Comment: When you say `traces`, do you mean diagnostics data that goes into WADTraceLogs table?

Comment: no, our system is logging some counters and other measured to a different table.

Comment: Is the PartitionKey in that table somehow depicts date/time like WAD* tables?

Answer (score 0):

Through your management console (http://manage.windowsazure.com) go to the table you want to know about and turn on monitoring for inserts. Depending on how deep down you want to go you might need to have geo replication turned on as well on the data.

Then take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh452240.aspx
MinuteMetrics is probably what you will use.